# Finding a polynomial $f(x)$ that when divided by $x+3$ yields quotient $2x^2-x+7$ and remainder $10$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I'm struggling to grasp this particular question:

> When a polynomial $f(x)$ is divided by $x+3$, the quotient is $2x^2-x+7$ and the remainder is $10$. What is $f(x)$?

This is what I did:

$$\begin{align}
f(x) &= (x+3)(2x^2-x+7) \\
&= 2x^3-x^2+7x+6x^2-3x+21 \\
&= 2x^3+5x^2+4x+21
\end{align}$$

Making sure it is correct:

[image]

Then, I realized that the remainder has to be 10 not 0...I have no idea how to do that

Comment: If you were doing ordinary division with numbers, you could divide $437$ by $23$, say, and get $19$ evenly.  Then if you wanted a number where the quotient was also $19$, but with a remainder of $10$, you would just add $10$ to the original number: $447$ divided by $23$ is $19$, with a remainder of $10$.

Comment: Oh, ok that makes much more sense, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Just add $10$ to your $f(x)$...it becomes the remainder when you do the division.

Answer (score 1):

In general, when you divide a function $p(x)$ by $q(x)$ and you get $f(x)$ as the quotient with a remainder of $r(x)$, you can alyways represent the answer as: $\frac{r(x)}{q(x)} + f(x)$

So you can rewrite your question algebraically as $\frac{10}{x+3} + 2x^2-x+7$ and then can simplify as follows:

$\frac{10}{x+3} + 2x^2-x+7 = \frac{10 + (x+3)(2x^2-x+7)}{x+3} = \frac{10 + 2x^3 -x^2+7x+6x^2-3x+21}{x+3} = \frac{2x^3 +5x^2 + 4x + 31}{x+3}$

Answer (score 1):

"Then, I realized that the remainder has to be 10 not 0...I have no idea how to do that"

Don't you?

If $f(x) = (x+3)(2x^2 -x + 7)$ then

$f(x) + r = (x+3)(2x^2-x +7) + r$

And $f(x) + 10 = (x+3)(2x^2-x +7) +10$.

And doesn't that mean the remainder of $f(x)\div (x+3) = 10$?

After all if we divide $(x+3)(2x^2 -x +7) + 10$ we'd get $\frac {(x+3)(2x^2 - x+ 7)}{x+3} = 2x^2 -x + 7$ and then .... we'd be left with the remainder of $10$.

So if you are told $f(x)$ divided by $d(x)$ has a quotient of $q(x)$ and a remainder of $r$ then you can just do $f(x) = d(x)q(x) + r$.

And so $g(x) = (x+3)(2x^2 - x+7) + 10=$

$(2x^3+5x^2+4x+21) + 10=$

$2x^3 + 5x^2 +4 + 31$

has to do it and if we did that we'd have:

[image]